# MongoDB Sharding On One Machine

Tags: mongodb

Does it make sense to implement mongodb sharding with say 100 shards on one beefier machine just to achieve higher concurrenct write into the database as I am told, there is a global lock for each monogod.exe process? Assuming that is possible, will that aproach give me higher write concurrency?

Comment: 100 shards is probably too many, but I wouldn't be surprised if you got better write performance with a few shards on a beefy server. Why not have your shards on separate less-beefy servers, though, as is usually done? What sort of insert/update rate do you expect to get?

Comment: The main reason is availability for a POC I need to do and I wondering if I could simulate a shard environment for the server that I have available. I assume a sever with 8 cores and 32gb of RAM is considered beefy. I am hoping to get 1000 concurrent writes and 10,000 concurrent read where each read or write request won't take more than 0.5second to be serviced by the database. Is this even reasonable with MongoDB? The query result size of each read and amount of data to write is not big and this is mostly about servicing the many concurrent read or write request to the db.

Comment: You insight here is appreciated. Do I even make sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running multiple mongods on a machine is not a good idea. Every one of the mongod processes will try to use all the available memory, forcing other mongod's memory mapped pages out of memory. This will create an enormous amount of swapping in most cases.

The global database lock is generally not a problem as is demonstrated in: http://blog.pythonisito.com/2011/12/mongodbs-write-lock.html

Only use one mongod per machine (but it's fine to add a mongos or config server as well), unless it's for some simple testing.

cheers,
Derick

Answer (score 2):

I totally disagree.  We run 8 shards per box in our setup.  It consists of two head nodes each with two other machines for replication.  6 boxes total.  These are beefy boxes with about 120GB of RAM, 32 Cores and 2TB each.  By having 8 shards per box (we could go higher by the way this is set at 8 for historic purposes) we make sure we utilize the CPU efficiently.  The RAM sorts itself out.  You do have to watch the metrics and make sure you aren't paging too much but with SSD drives (which we have) if you do spill onto the disk drives it isn't too bad.

Comment: How would RAM sort itself out? Also, did you decide to have so many shard for higher write throughput or something else?

Comment: We used the Mongo Map Reduce (MR) and it needs CPU power to process all the data.  The original sharding was setup with a shard per core.  This gave us the maximum CPU.  Since then the box has been upgraded so we are now at a shard per 4 cores.  As for memory it is an exercise in keeping the indexes in RAM.  The data will never fit so don't even worry about that.  We monitor our index size relative to RAM and have upgraded to accommodate.  We have also dropped indexes we don't need.

Answer (score 1):

The only use case where I found running several mongod on the same server was to increase replication speed on high latency connection.

As highlighted by Derick, the write lock is not really your issue when running mongodb.

To answer your question : **yes** you can demonstrate mongo scaling with several instance per machine (4 instances per server sems to be enough) if your test does not involve too much data (otherwise page out will dramatically decrase your performance, I have already tested it)

However, instances will still **compete** for resources. All you will manage to do is to shift the database lock issue to a resource lock issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can and in fact that's what we do for 50+ mil write-heavy database. Just make sure all your indexes per mongod fit into the RAM and there's room for growth and maintenance.

However, there's a small trade-off: Depending on what your target QPS is, this kind of sharing requires machines with more horsepower, whereas sharding on a single machine will not and in most cases you can do away with commodity, cheaper hardware.

Whatever the case is, do the series of performance tests (ageinst IO, Network, PQS etc) and establish your baseline carefully and consider SSD drives for storage and this may sound biased, but Linux XFS storage is also something to consider.